# Emberjs/Rails App Not Loading on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ember.js, ruby-on-rails-4

Trying to deploy a Rails 4, Ruby 2, MySQL app to Heroku with the ClearDB plugin to handle MySQL but trying to load the home page results in this in the server logs.  Any thoughts on what it means?

```
at=info method=GET path=/ host=whispering-lake-7719.herokuapp.com fwd="76.24.27.108" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=75ms status=304 bytes=0
Started GET "/assets/application-780385875af2448947950232fb279cb6.js" for 76.24.27.108 at 2013-08-22 04:39:41 +0000
Processing by HomeController#index as JS
  Parameters: {"ember"=>8947950232fb279cb6"}
  Rendered home/index.html.erb (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 2ms (Views: 1.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Started GET "/" for 76.24.27.108 at 2013-08-22 04:41:17 +0000
Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
  Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 22ms (Views: 1.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Started GET "/assets/application-58c7c0e35a67f189e19b8c485930e614.css" for 76.24.27.108 at 2013-08-22 04:41:17 +0000
Processing by HomeController#index as CSS
  Parameters: {"ember"=>"assets/application-58c7c0e35a67f189e19b8c485930e614"}
method=GET path=/assets/application-58c7c0e35a67f189e19b8c485930e614.css host=whispering-lake-7719.herokuapp.com fwd="76.24.27.108" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=70ms status=500 bytes=1266
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 6ms

ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template home/index, application/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:css], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
* "/app/app/views"
* "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails-2.2.7/app/views"
* "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.0.0/app/views"
):
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the rails_12factor gem to the gemfile under the production group fixed this issue.